# EPPLUS - Issue with formulas not working on cells

Tags: c#-4.0, epplus-4

I am using the excellent EPPLUS library to add a record to an excel spreadsheet.

workSheet.Cells[CurrentRow, ExcelColIndex].FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(G3="Yes",0,NUMBERVALUE(F3))";
workSheet.Calculate();

The code works and the spreadsheet is successfully saved, but when I open the spreadsheet again, Excel throws an error

It works without issue if I am just updating an existing row.
Error @ applied on formula tag as below
=@IF(G3="Yes",0,NUMBERVALUE(F3))